# Remove duplicate operators that are next to each other not numbers

Tags: javascript

Unique order list of items without any operators with the same value next to each other and preserving the original order of elements but this doesn't have to work with numbers just operators +-x/,
the problem of my code is that it works with numbers too I don't want to remove any duplicates about numbers jus the operators.

```
        function uniqueInOrder(x) {
          const result = [];
          const input = Array.isArray(x) ? x : x.split('');



             for (let i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
              if (input[i] == input[i + 1]) continue
                result.push(input[i])
            }

            return result
             }

          console.log(uniqueInOrder('1++222+44//43--44'));
```

Comment: `const uniqueInOrder = x=>x.replace(/([+\-x/])\1+/g,"$1");` Done.

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally check numbers:

```
input[i]!=1*input[i] //not a number
```

```js
function uniqueInOrder(x) {
        const result = [];
        const input = Array.isArray(x) ? x : x.split('');



       for (let i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
              if (input[i] == input[i + 1] && input[i]!=1*input[i]) continue
              result.push(input[i])
       }

      return result
}

console.log(uniqueInOrder('1++222+44//43--44'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? It removes all duplicate operators and just leaves the first one.

```
const p = '1++222+44//43--44';

/*
What the regular expression is doing is to first find any operator +,-,*,/ that is followed by one or more other operators.

The entire match is then replaced with the first found operator.
*/
const regex = /([-+*\/])[-+*\/]+/gi;

console.log(p.replace(regex, '$1')); // "1+222+44/43-44"
```